# The tax for shipping and handling is displayed twice on my PDF invoices

Tags: invoice, pdf

We have a issue with our invoice grand total where the shipping tax is added twice.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I need this solved too.

Answer (score 1):

This is Magento core bug, here is source of fix https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf/commit/0f96532a870a32ce1cea2730f6afbe14e1863407

You need to overwrite app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php can change line

```
foreach ($total->getTotalsForDisplay() as $totalData) {
```

to

```
$uniqueTotalsForDisplay = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $total->getTotalsForDisplay())));
                 foreach ($uniqueTotalsForDisplay as $totalData) {
```

This is not best solution but works good as hotfix, not edit core directly!